# When I change the content of div, the div stay with the old content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I'm uploading a different files into one div,

and the div does not refresh' it stay all the time with the same content.

Here is my code:

ASPX

```
<div id="txtHazara"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
if(user=="Manager")
   $('#Div1').load('Manager.aspx');
else
   $('#Div1').load('Secretary.aspx');
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Obviously your Javascript code expects to find a `<div id="Div1">...</div>` somewhere in the code. Do you have one? In your markup you only give a `<div id="txtHazara"></div>` - with ID txtHazara

Answer (score 3):

Your jquery code use wrong div id.

jquery code:

```
if(user=="Manager")
   $('#txtHazara').load('Manager.aspx');
else
   $('#txtHazara').load('Secretary.aspx');
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is : "**txtHazara**", 
So your code should be like this :

```
if(user=="Manager")
   $('#txtHazara').load('Manager.aspx');
else
   $('#txtHazara').load('Secretary.aspx');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First clear your div content

```
<div id="txtHazara"></div>
```

**jQuery Script:**

```
if (user == "Manager") {
    $('#txtHazara').html('').load('Manager.aspx');      
} else {
    $('#txtHazara').html('').load('Secretary.aspx');        
}
```